# The CSS "Quote in a Quote" Issue

Tags: css, css-selectors, quotes

I'm trying to find a solution to the following problem, if there is any.

Lets say the primary quote sign is a double top quote “ (start) and ” (end). And let's also say the secondary quote sign is a single top quote ‘ (start) and ’ (end).

Think about how a quote in a quote is shown.

The standard of writing quotes is, of course, alternating, like this.

> “Double ‘single “double ‘single’ double” single’ double.”

Now, in HTML, you would write this:

```
<q>Double <q>single <q>double <q>single </q>double </q>single </q>double.</q>
```

But no, this won't work without applying CSS rules. I'm not going to use the :lang pseudo selector here, so I'm just leaving it without.

```css
q:before,
q q q:before,
q q q q q:before { content: '“' }

q:after,
q q q:after,
q q q q q:after { content: '”' }

q q:before,
q q q q:before,
q q q q q q:before { content: '‘' }

q q:after,
q q q q:after,
q q q q q q:after { content: '’' }
```

You see where this is going, right? The qs add up and up.

So now there are two options: either I'm not seeing the logical way to select the q elements in the right order or it just isn't possible.

PS: I know it is very theoretical to have a quote in a quote in a quote in a quote in a quote.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - alternate nested styles (not possible)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055299/css-alternate-nested-styles-not-possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get this to work with just CSS selectors `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` since they're nested, but it is possible using jQuery:

First define your CSS classes:

```css
.e:before {content:'“'}
.o:before {content:'‘'}
.e:after {content:'”'}
.o:after {content:'’'}
```

Then use jQuery to add the class to every even/odd quote:

```
$("q:odd").addClass('o');
$("q:even").addClass('e');
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/upofun/1/edit)

Related questions:

- [CSS refer to every odd nested child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499496/css-refer-to-every-odd-nested-child)
- [querySelector with nested nth-child in Chrome doesn't appear to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345358/queryselector-with-nested-nth-child-in-chrome-doesnt-appear-to-work)

Comment: Not a bad solution, but people should be careful because jQuery's `:odd` pseudo-selector doesn't work quite the way the CSS `:nth-child(odd)` does.

Comment: Right, which is what allows this solution to work. `$("q")` will give me all the quote elements and `:odd` will take the odd ones. The CSS selector only selects the odd elements at the same level under the parent.

Comment: Thanks, now I also learned that the jQuery odd selector doesn't equal the CSS odd selector.

Let's hope CSS4 will feature a selector like that natively. =)

Comment: And it shouldn't. Given a list of elements, odd selects the odd ones. jQuery also has `nth-child()` which is the same as the CSS selector. CSS, on the other hand, does not have an `odd` selector, which is why we have to use jQuery for this.

Comment: People need to remember that `:nth-child()` is called `:nth-child()` and not `:nth-element()` or `:nth()` for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to write a rule that catches the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. vs. 2nd, 4th, 6th levels of identical nested elements, recursively for any *n* levels.

Apart from the theoretical problem, you'd have to set classes and/or use javascript.

Answer (score 2):

CSS2.1 has features designed specifically for handling [quotation marks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#quotes). The `quotes` property in particular has rudimentary support for nesting, but it can only support nesting to an arbitrary depth and not recursive or repeated nesting.

So while currently there isn't a CSS solution that covers all nesting levels, you can specify quotes as deeply as necessary while saving quite a few bytes from hardcoding nested `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements in your selectors:

```css
q { quotes: '“' '”' '‘' '’' '“' '”' '‘' '’' '“' '”' '‘' '’' '“' '”' '‘' '’'; }

/* 
 * These should already be in the default UA stylesheet per HTML specs
 * so you should not have to include them, but some older browsers may forget.
 */
q:before { content: open-quote; }
q:after { content: close-quote; }
```

You don't need to worry about browser support because it's pretty much the same for the HTML `q` element and the CSS `quotes` property as for `:before` and `:after`.

There aren't any CSS3 modules in active development yet that address this issue with quote generation, but hopefully we'll see something soon.