# JS: Create a CSS selector string from an HTML element

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, queryselector

In JavaScript, given I have selected an HTML element, for example:

```
<div id="some-id" class="class-1 class-2">...</div>
```

Is there an easy way to create the corresponding CSS selector/QuerySelector?

```
"div#some-id.class-1.class-2"
```

Or is the only way to construct this string manually using tagName, id and classList?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48081741) maybe helps

Comment: @ericmp Easier than tagName, id and classList?

Comment: im kinda confused on what u want to achieve. if u want to select an element by id u can use `document.querySelector('#some-id')`. not sure what is ur question

Comment: @ericmp thanks, that seems to be like what I was thinking about. If you write that as an answer, I will mark it as answered (if no better solutions show up).

Comment: @Andy I am not trying to select the element. I want to convert an element to a string presentation in the QuerySelector syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tagName, id and classList are quite simple to use if you want a list of selectors

If you have an ID, you do not need the rest:

```js
const divSelectors = tag => [...document.querySelectorAll(tag)]
  .map(tag => tag.id ? `#${tag.id}` : `${tag.tagName.toLowerCase()}${tag.classList.length ? `.${[...tag.classList].join('.')}` : ''}`)
console.log(divSelectors("div"))
```

```html
<div>...</div>
<div id="id1" class="class-1 class-2">...</div>
<div id="id2" class="class-3 class-4">...</div>
<div id="id3" class="class-5 class-6">...</div>
<div class="class-7 class-8">...</div>
<div id="id4">...</div>
```

But if you insist:

```js
const divSelectors = tag => [...document.querySelectorAll(tag)]
  .map(tag => `${tag.tagName.toLowerCase()}${tag.id?`#${tag.id}`:''}${tag.classList.length ? `.${[...tag.classList].join('.')}` : ''}`)
console.log(divSelectors("div"))
```

```html
<div>...</div>
<div id="id1" class="class-1 class-2">...</div>
<div id="id2" class="class-3 class-4">...</div>
<div id="id3" class="class-5 class-6">...</div>
<div class="class-7 class-8">...</div>
<div id="id4">...</div>
```

Surprisingly enough we can use querySelector on multiple divs with the same ID

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#aDiv").textContent)
console.log(document.querySelector("#aDiv.three.four").textContent)

console.log([...document.querySelectorAll("#aDiv")].map(div => div.textContent))
```

```html
<div id="aDiv" class="one two">First</div>
<div id="aDiv" class="three four">Second</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that is some condensed code. 

Comment: There's a bug when there are no classes: <div> -> "div0". Also, if there is an ID, then technically you could omit classes also. But note that in the real world there are documents with duplicate IDs.

Comment: I fixed a small bug where the leading dot for the classes was missing.

Comment: All works again.

Comment: As HTML can't have "fatal" errors, the rule about unique IDs is more like a guideline. So browsers have to handle duplicate IDs, so in reality IDs are just a special kind of class.

Comment: However your JS can fail to work on duplicate IDs :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution for you problem

```js
function createCssSelector(el){
    return `${el.nodeName}${el.id ? '#'+el.id : ''}${el.getAttribute('class') ? '.'+el.getAttribute('class').split(' ').join('.') : ''}`;
}

console.log(createCssSelector(document.querySelector('#some-id')));

console.log(createCssSelector(document.querySelector('#some-id-2')));

console.log(createCssSelector(document.querySelector('span')));

console.log(createCssSelector(document.querySelector('#some-id-3')));
```

```html
<div id="some-id" class="class-1 class-2 class-4">...</div>

<p id="some-id-2" class="black blue white">...</p>

<span class="black blue white">...</span>

<p id="some-id-3" class="">...</p>
```

Comment: This breaks in case there are no classes, and will always output "#" even if there is no id. (I see my question was not clear about that, have edited the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Having this HTML:

```html
<div id="some-id" class="class-1 class-2">...</div>
```

You can select the div using different techniques/ways:

```js
document.querySelector("#some-id")

document.querySelector(".class-1.class-2")

document.getElementById("some-id")

document.querySelector("#some-id.class-1.class-2")

...
```

Depending on what are you doing you want to use one or other one. If there is no context, I'd stick to the first one.

* (Extra tip) If you are in a web browser, you can:

1. Open up the DevTools.
2. Click on the cursor icon - "Select an element in the page to inspect it".

[image]

3. Click an element in the page.
4. Go to the devtools console.
5. Write `$0`. If you don't return, it will show you the full selector.

[image]

5. If you return, it will log you the selected element.

[image]

Documentation:

- [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: You a correct, basically what I want is a function that returns the string you see in DevTools. ("div#some-id.class-1.class-2")